# How to install python application with tkcalendar module by pyinstaller?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, tkcalendar

I'm trying to install python application on Windows with pyinstaller where I'm using tkcalendar. Application is working but the tkcalendar.Calendar isn't.

When I'm running application without installation everything works but if I do this, Calendar widget does not appear.
I think that pyinstaller sees this module but he has problems with modules that tkcalendar is using.
I tried to run pyinstaller with --path=/.../python/Lib/site-packages but this didnt worked. Also copying module files to application directory didn't help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue does not come from `tkcalendar` but from the fact that PyInstaller does not detect second level imports. A way to solve this issue is explained in tkcalendar's documentation in the [HowTos](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howtos.html#pyinstaller) section:

> When bundling an application with PyInstaller, there is an 
>   [issue](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/32) with the
>   detection of the babel dependency of tkcalendar. This can be fixed by
>   using the `--hidden-import` option:
>
> ```
> $ pyinstaller --hidden-import babel.numbers myscript.py
> ```
>
> or by editing the *.spec* file:
>
> ```
> hiddenimports=["babel.numbers"]
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Add following code to your python script, while bundling with pyinstaller

```
import babel.numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone found the same problem.
In tkcalendar 1.5.0 there is problem with import in calendar.py.

Locate the **tkcalendar** folder (probably /.../python/Lib/site-packages/tkcalendar) and under **calendar.py** add an additional import for the missing module:

````py
import calendar
from babel.dates import format_date, parse_date, get_day_names, get_month_names
from babel.numbers import *  # Additional Import```
````