# Python, executive failed to execute (fatal error detected)

Tags: python, datepicker

I am trying to convert a python script to an executive file (through pyinstaller), but once I get the executive, it appears the usual pop-up:

"Fatal error detected"
"Failed to execute script ..."

I guess the issue stays in the date_picker, in every GUI I tried to convert in execute with at least a date_picker I got that error

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import*
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
ent = DateEntry(root, width=15, backgroundcolor="blue", foregroundcolor="red", borderwidth=3)
ent.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Could it be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811928/how-to-install-python-application-with-tkcalendar-module-by-pyinstaller?