# Error when run exe "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers"

Tags: exe, babeljs, modulenotfounderror, tkcalendar

When I try to run my .exe file I get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'

I add this line
"from babel.numbers import *"
into  calendar_.py file but nothing changed.
How to fix this error?

Comment: I solved the problem using this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811928/how-to-install-python-application-with-tkcalendar-module-by-pyinstaller