# I create a 'GUI Application' with Python but when I converted it to an EXE file via the auto_py_to_exe tool why did I get this error message?

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, tkcalendar, auto-py-to-exe

I was creating a **GUI Application** with `Python` but when I converted it to an **EXE** file via the **auto_py_to_exe** tool why did I get this error message?

ERROR message..

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "School MS.py", line 182, in <module>
  File "tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 128, in __init__
  File "tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 258, in __init__
  File "babel\dates.py", line 353, in get_day_names
  File "babel\core.py", line 641, in days
  File "babel\core.py", line 364, in _data
  File "babel\localedata.py", line 141, in load
  File "babel\localedata.py", line 147, in load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'
[13604] Failed to execute script 'School MS' due to unhandled exception!

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the issue in [How to install python application with tkcalendar module by pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811928/how-to-install-python-application-with-tkcalendar-module-by-pyinstaller)

Indeed, after looking into [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe), I realized that this is just a GUI around PyInstaller. Therefore the solution is the same, you need to pass `babel.numbers` to the `--hidden-import` option, in the *Advanced* section in the GUI.