# failed to excute due to unhandled exception no module named babel.numbers

Tags: python, tkinter, python-babel, tkcalendar

i built a python app with tkinter and i want to make it into an exe so i can use it as a normal app. the problem is pyinstaller is always throwing weird errors (i don't know if this has to do with windows 11 because in windows 10 i wasn't getting such errors) so i changed to another tool called auto-py-to-exe it's an easy interface that does all the job and it was able to convert all my python apps to exe successfully except this one.

it throws an error that says, "failed to execute (the file name) due to unhandled exception: no module named babel.numbers".

why is that i have no idea. but the issue comes from a module i used which is an addon to tkinter called tkcalendar which makes displaying calendars in tkinter apps easy.

[image: this is what the error says when trying to run the generated exe]

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install python application with tkcalendar module by pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811928/how-to-install-python-application-with-tkcalendar-module-by-pyinstaller)